# C++ Error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c++, pascal

I am new to C++ and I have a problem where i have to transform a pseudocode in C++ / C / Pascal language. The answer at the end of the book written in Pascal.

The problem in my C++ code is that at the line 12, I get the error which can be found in the title. Any idea?

Pascal Code:

```
var n,x:integer;
begin
  n:=0;
repeat
  write('x=');read(X);
  if x<>0 then
    if x mod 5 = 0 then 
      n:=n+1
    else 
      n:=n-1;
until x=0;
if n=0 then 
  write('yes')
else 
  write('no')
end;
```

My C++ Code:

```
int main()
{
    int x,n;
    cin>>x;
    while(x>0)
    {
        if(x>0)
        {
            if(x%5=0){
                n=n+1; 
            } else {
                n=n-1;
            }
        }
        if(n=0){
            cout<<"Yes"<<;
        } else {
            cout<<"No"<<; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Line 12 is "if(x%5=0){"

Comment: while we are at it: `if (n=0)` should probably be `if (n == 0)` as well. but you should really **turn on compiler warnings** and **learn the basics of the language** before wasting our time by asking trivially-answerable questions.

Comment: Also, indent your code and remove extra consecutive blank lines for readability,

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple typo: `if(x%5=0){` is an attempt to *assign* 0 to `x % 5` (due to operator precedence modulus is computed before assignment). `x % 5` cannot be assigned to (it's not an lvalue) and the compiler is telling you that.

The fix, of course, is to write `x % 5 == 0`.

You're lucky in this case that the error is picked up at *compile-time*. Something like `if (n = 0)` (on line 18) might not be, since `x = 0` is an *expression* with value 0.

Two ways to guard against that:

- Ensure that your compiler warnings are as aggressive as you can bear.  With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra`, and that combination is enough to catch this common problem.
- Some developers will write `if (0 == x)` since an errant `if (0 = x)` would be picked up at compile time as an attempt to assign to `0`. Personally, I find that obfuscating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use == in conditions (while, if, ...) for equality check  in C++.

Comment: Thank you. Such a small problem

Comment: "egality" -> "equality"

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator requires lvalue means the left side operand need to be a variable/location that can hold a value.
This is what is meant by the error.
What you need in your if statement is == likely not assignment as mentioned by other answers

Answer (score 0):

> if(x%5 = 0)

should be

> if(x%5 == 0)

"x%5" is not an lvalue in that you can not assign a value to it, hence the error.